# SQL Syntax Issue

Tags: join, sql

I'm joining two tables and making a simple count, but I can't seem to rename the joined key variable into something more appropriate for the two tables, I keep getting the error '"CUSTOMER_NO" is not valid in the context where it is used.'  I'm sure it's just a little syntax error, but I can't see it...

```
SELECT owner_no AS customer_no,

CASE
WHEN customer_no BETWEEN 5000 and 5999 THEN 'RENTER'
WHEN customer_no BETWEEN 6000 and 6999 THEN 'OWNER'
END AS customer_type

FROM owner_phone AS op
INNER JOIN renter_phone AS rp ON op.owner_no = rp.renter_no

GROUP BY customer_no
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the actual column name in your CASE and GROUP BY, not the aliased column name.

```
CASE
WHEN owner_no BETWEEN 5000 and 5999 THEN 'RENTER'
WHEN owner_no BETWEEN 6000 and 6999 THEN 'OWNER'
END AS customer_type

FROM owner_phone AS op
INNER JOIN renter_phone AS rp ON op.owner_no = rp.renter_no
GROUP BY owner_no
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: @jimconstable : You were both right, thank you.  Second minimal question, if owner_no and renter_no contain different values, I should use the union function instead of the inner join correct?

Comment: @Eric, what connects owner_no and renter_no. Is it a building ID, an address, something else? Perhaps you can post a new question which shows your database schema, some sample data, and the outcome you're looking to reach, and we can help you get there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use OWNER_NO through the rest of your query but leave the AS CUSTOMER_NO to make that the column name.

```
SELECT owner_no AS customer_no,
CASE
    WHEN owner_no BETWEEN 5000 and 5999 THEN 'RENTER'
    WHEN owner_no BETWEEN 6000 and 6999 THEN 'OWNER'
END AS customer_type
FROM owner_phone AS op
INNER JOIN renter_phone AS rp ON op.owner_no = rp.renter_no
GROUP BY owner_no 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```